# Is it possible to detect type when a static is called on a derived type

Tags: c#, static

Given

```
public class Original {
  public static DoStuff() {
  }
}

public class Derived : Original {
}
```

when calling

```
Derived.DoStuff();
```

Weirdness of the requirement aside, is it possible within `DoStuff()` to detect the class that it was called on?

i.e. is it possible within the implementation of `DoStuff()` to tell the difference between `Original.DoStuff();` and `Derived.DoStuff();`

Comment: Whats it got to do with it being static?

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: @CarstenKönig when you have a Core library that uses an Active-record style pattern and you want to create a derived class eg. `class MyAppUser : SystemCoreUser` and using something like `MyAppUser.Load(id)`. You could use reflection within the static method to new-up the correct type. I acknowledge that that's a weird request and there are better patterns, I was just curious.

Comment: I have seen the pattern `public class Derived : Original<Derived>` before for this purpose (the curiously recurring generic pattern), but I recomned against it, as most style analysis tools will flag this as a warning, telling you to call `Original<Derived>.DoStuff()` directly, (since calling a static method through a derived class is usually misleading, and frequently a mistake).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in C#, no - the compiled IL refers directly to `Original.DoStuff`.

(I've just verified that VB apparently does the same thing for static calls, whereas IIRC there's a difference between VB and C# in the generated code when calling a *virtual* method via a "child" reference.)

Answer (score 1):

Unless `Derived` provides its own definition of `DoStuff`, `Derived.DoStuff()` is equivalent to `Original.DoStuff()`.  Static methods/member variables are associated with the class, not with any of the instances (objects).

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said, not possible in C# because static methods have unique entry points. Anyway you are right, it's very weird that one would need to detect it.